# FinderにGitステータスを表示する方法

Tags: git, macos

[Atom](https://atom.io/)やIDEだと、ファイルのGit状況をツリービューで表示してくれて便利です。同様の機能をFinderで提供するものってないのでしょうか? イメージとしては、Dropboxのファイルバッジみたいなのが理想的です。

[image: Dropboxのファイルバッジ]

[StackOverflow(英語版)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107540/git-client-integrated-with-finder)だと、[PathFinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/)が回答に上がっていますが、別アプリケーションではなくFinderでできるのが望ましいです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

アプリの信頼度とかは全く不明ですが、Finder BoostというのでGitのStatusを表示出来るようです。
http://hobbyistsoftware.com/finderBoost

Comment: おおお、すばらしい。ありがとうございます。先にYosemiteに上げなきゃですが、試してみます!